# Recursion String out of Bounds

Tags: java, string, recursion

```
void two(int i)
{
    if(i<s.length());
    {
        char a=s.charAt(i);
        if(a==' ')
            a-=2;               
        a+=2;
        if((a<64||a>90)&&a!=32)
            a-=26;
        System.out.print(a);
        two(i+1);
    }
}
```

`s` is a global variable. When I execute, it gives my output correctly, but at the end it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 12
```

What is happening when the computer closes its workspaces in executing this recursive method?

Comment: Change `if(i<s.length());` to `if(i<s.length())`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon after the `if` statement, as it represents just an empty statement that's being executed once per a method called. This makes the remaining statements within the brackets not bound to the `if` statement and they are executed every time the method is called.

Since you increase the index `i` on each recursive call and the statements in the brackets are executed independently from the `if`, then you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on `char a=s.charAt(i);`

```
if(i<s.length());
                ↑
```

You should end up with something like:

```
if(i<s.length()) {
    char a=s.charAt(i);
    if(a==' ')
        a-=2;               
    a+=2;
    if((a<64||a>90)&&a!=32)
        a-=26;
    System.out.print(a);
    two(i+1);
}
```